# Adding an auto brush to the d3 timeline chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, brush

I am working on a d3 timeline chart -- but on load - I want the brush to be automatically deployed -- with the option of fine-tuning on a particular set of in/out dates

[image]
https://jsfiddle.net/nu1z4d3r/

https://jsfiddle.net/2y8gkas3/8/  -- latest example --

I've tried adding the -- draw brush logic to the bottom of the code base
https://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/3cda05ca68cba260cb81

- what would be the correct values to make this work -- should xTop be x2?

  function drawBrush(a, b) {
    // define our brush extent

  ```
    // define our brush extent

    // note that x0 and x1 refer to the lower and upper bound of the brush extent
    // while x2 refers to the scale for the second x-axis, for the context or brush area.
    // unfortunate variable naming :-/
    var x0 = xTop.invert(a*w)
    var x1 = xTop.invert(b*w)
    console.log("x0", x0)
    console.log("x1", x1)
    brush.extent([x0, x1])

    // now draw the brush to match our extent
    // use transition to slow it down so we can see what is happening
    // set transition duration to 0 to draw right away
    //brush(d3.select(".brush").transition().duration(500));

    // now fire the brushstart, brushmove, and brushend events
    // set transition the delay and duration to 0 to draw right away
    //brush.event(d3.select(".brush").transition().delay(1000).duration(500));

  }

      // call drawBrush once on load with the default value
  //var zoomA = d3.select("input#a")[0][0].value;
  //var zoomB = d3.select("input#b")[0][0].value;

  var zoomA = 0;
  var zoomB = -1;
  drawBrush(zoomA, zoomB);

      /*
  // update the extent and call drawBrush again
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    d3.select("input#a")[0][0].value = .2;
    d3.select("input#b")[0][0].value = .7;
    var zoomA = d3.select("input#a")[0][0].value;
    var zoomB = d3.select("input#b")[0][0].value; 
    drawBrush(zoomA, zoomB) 
  }, 2500); 
  */
  ```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2y8gkas3/7/  -- latest example --

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2y8gkas3/11/  -- adding date in tooltip

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m6ueL79o/3/  -- resolved -- solution to activate the brush is here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the brush -- there were some modifications I had to make

https://jsfiddle.net/m6ueL79o/3/

where the brush is called -- we append a variable to the artefact. We make a 2nd call with "brush.move, x1.range()" -- this loads the scrubber

```
  var brush = d3.brushX()
  .extent([[0, 0], [w, miniHeight]])
  .on("brush", brushed);

  var gBrush = mini.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x brush")
    .call(brush)  
    .call(brush.move, x1.range());
```

---

otherwise -- to load just the chart first -- do not have the .call(brush.move... and at the base add  "drawBrush(timeBegin, timeEnd);"